# toggle dark mode on laravel-breeze application

Tags: html, laravel, web, breeze, laravel-10

When I create a new Laravel (laravel 10) application with dark mode using the Breeze package I want to create a button to toggle the dark mode

how to add button with change dark mode to light mode

i try manually find dark mode
for  ex. resources > views > welcome.blade.php

find 'prefers-color-scheme' and change in to dart to light
note : it changed only the welcome page